# What is public/manifest.json file in create-react-app?

Tags: reactjs, manifest, create-react-app

I know that chrome extensions use 'manifest.json`, but here, it is used as something else as well.

contents -

```
{
  "short_name": "React App",
  "name": "Create React App Sample",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "favicon.ico",
      "sizes": "192x192",
      "type": "image/png"
    }
  ],
  "start_url": "./index.html",
  "display": "standalone",
  "theme_color": "#000000",
  "background_color": "#ffffff"
}
```

When I change some value, page update, but nothing changes.

Answer (score 218, accepted):

It's a [Web App Manifest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Manifest) that describes your application and it's used by e.g. mobile phones if a shortcut is added to the homescreen.

From MDN (linked above):

> The web app manifest provides information about an application (such as name, author, icon, and description) in a JSON text file. The purpose of the manifest is to install web applications to the homescreen of a device, providing users with quicker access and a richer experience.

Comment: NOTE: seems, like they updated the description slightly, I guess there might be more use cases now.
"The most common use for a web application manifest is to provide information that the browser needs to install a progressive web app (PWA) on a device, such as the app's name and icon."

Answer (score 7):

manifest.json is the json file that is mostly used to describe our app on mobile phones.

Answer (score 3):

The manifest.json provides information about a web application in a JSON text file, necessary for the web app to be downloaded and be presented to the user similarly to a native app (e.g., be installed on the homescreen of a device, providing users with quicker access and a richer experience). PWA manifests include its name, author, icon(s), version, description, and list of all the necessary resources (among other things).