# How can flask serve the react public files

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, flask

In react, I created a folder `./public/assets`, and put an image in the `./public/assets`. Everything works well when I run `npm start`.
After running `npm run build` in react, I get a `./build` folder. I copied files and folders inside the `./build` folder to a flask folder. Since the `index.html` should be put in `./templates` in flask, the browser can't get the image in flask `./assets`.

The files in flask:

```
.
├── app.py
├── asset-manifest.json
├── assets
│   └── Montage_of_Toronto_7.jpg
├── favicon.ico
├── manifest.json
├── precache-manifest.28e9dd49c9646209098c5bb088bdb16f.js
├── service-worker.js
├── static
│   ├── css
│   │   ├── main.2cce8147.chunk.css
│   │   └── main.2cce8147.chunk.css.map
│   ├── js
│   │   ├── 2.38e0f74c.chunk.js
│   │   ├── 2.38e0f74c.chunk.js.map
│   │   ├── main.1c5ab122.chunk.js
│   │   ├── main.1c5ab122.chunk.js.map
│   │   ├── runtime~main.a8a9905a.js
│   │   └── runtime~main.a8a9905a.js.map
│   └── media
│       └── logo.5d5d9eef.svg
└── templates
    └── index.html
```

the folders in react/public:

```
.
├── assets
│   └── Montage_of_Toronto_7.jpg
├── favicon.ico
├── index.html
└── manifest.json
```

the files in react/build

```
.
├── asset-manifest.json
├── assets
│   └── Montage_of_Toronto_7.jpg
├── favicon.ico
├── index.html
├── manifest.json
├── precache-manifest.28e9dd49c9646209098c5bb088bdb16f.js
├── service-worker.js
└── static
    ├── css
    │   ├── main.2cce8147.chunk.css
    │   └── main.2cce8147.chunk.css.map
    ├── js
    │   ├── 2.38e0f74c.chunk.js
    │   ├── 2.38e0f74c.chunk.js.map
    │   ├── main.1c5ab122.chunk.js
    │   ├── main.1c5ab122.chunk.js.map
    │   ├── runtime~main.a8a9905a.js
    │   └── runtime~main.a8a9905a.js.map
    └── media
        └── logo.5d5d9eef.svg
```

Is there any solution that can configure the public path so that the `./public` folder will be put into `./build/static`?

I use `send_from_directory` in flask backend to serve the files in `./assets`. But I would like to put files to `./build/static` folder when I run `npm run build`, including the files `favicon.ico`, `manifest.json` and so on.

Comment: are you using create-react-app?

Comment: @CaioLopes yes `npx create-react-app my-app `

Answer (score 3):

If you have a build directory like this inside the flask app:

```
.
|
|_build
|    |_static
|       |_css
|       |_js
|       |_img
|    |_index.html
|_serve.py
```

With a `serve.py` like this:

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template, send_from_directory


app = Flask(__name__, static_folder="build/static", template_folder="build")


@app.route("/")
def home():
    return render_template('index.html')


@app.route("/manifest.json")
def manifest():
    return send_from_directory('./build', 'manifest.json')


@app.route('/favicon.ico')
def favicon():
    return send_from_directory('./build', 'favicon.ico')


app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True)
```

Reference:
https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/favicon/

I think it will work.

Full directory tree (tested here locally):

```
.
├── README.md
├── build
│   ├── asset-manifest.json
│   ├── favicon.ico
│   ├── index.html
│   ├── manifest.json
│   ├── precache-manifest.054774adbe886ee6e3c29227ef1745b5.js
│   ├── service-worker.js
│   └── static
│       ├── css
│       │   ├── main.2cce8147.chunk.css
│       │   └── main.2cce8147.chunk.css.map
│       ├── js
│       │   ├── 2.b41502e9.chunk.js
│       │   ├── 2.b41502e9.chunk.js.map
│       │   ├── main.28647029.chunk.js
│       │   ├── main.28647029.chunk.js.map
│       │   ├── runtime~main.a8a9905a.js
│       │   └── runtime~main.a8a9905a.js.map
│       └── media
│           └── logo.5d5d9eef.svg
├── package.json
├── public
│   ├── favicon.ico
│   ├── index.html
│   └── manifest.json
├── serve.py
├── src
│   ├── App.css
│   ├── App.js
│   ├── App.test.js
│   ├── index.css
│   ├── index.js
│   ├── logo.svg
│   └── serviceWorker.js
└── yarn.lock
```

In this case, I merged the flask and the react app in the same directory. You can put in different directories and then just move the `build` dir to the root of the flask app. Or do like this suggestion [like this](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/1354#issuecomment-299956790).

**EDIT (another option to do it):**

You can also edit your public directory to look like this:

```
public/
├── index.html
└── static
    ├── favicon.ico
    └── manifest.json
```

Note you should also change your index.html to have:

```html
<link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/static/manifest.json" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/static/favicon.ico" />
```

Then, when you run `yarn build` you will have the `favicon.ico` and `manifest.json` inside the static directory. No need to have the custom routes on flask for this.

Comment: No, it doesn't work. Did you try `app.run()`? If you load `http://127.0.0.1:5000/` and open the Chrome network panel, can you see manifest.json `404`?

Comment: @combo-combo Indeed... I added an workaround but I don't think it is a good solution, but it works

Comment: But I don't think you can put this inside static since it is expected to be on the root. You can read more about this manifest.json file here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45186993/what-is-public-manifest-json-file-in-create-react-app

Comment: Found another way to do it. Edited the original solution.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this can help:

1. react build folder

```
build
├── asset-manifest.json
├── favicon.ico
├── index.html
├── logo192.png
├── logo512.png
├── manifest.json
├── precache-manifest.984ab282787c862e232c323b865ef221.js
├── robots.txt
├── service-worker.js
└── static\
```

2. serve public resources using regex

```
import flask
from werkzeug.routing import BaseConverter

class RegexConverter(BaseConverter):
    def __init__(self, url_map, *items):
        super(RegexConverter, self).__init__(url_map)
        self.regex = items[0]

app = flask.Flask(__name__, template_folder='build', static_folder='build/static')
app.url_map.converters['regex'] = RegexConverter

@app.route("/<regex(r'(.*?)\.(json|txt|png|ico|js)$'):file>", methods=["GET"])
def public(file):
    return flask.send_from_directory('./build', file)
```