# Chrome Extension: "Error while trying to use the following icon from the Manifest" for a png that is not in my app

Tags: google-chrome-extension, twitter, manifest.json

I'm developing an extension that modifies the content on Twitter / X, I'm *occasionally* getting this error:

*Error while trying to use the following icon from the Manifest: https://abs.twimg.com/responsive-web/client-web/icon-default.522d363a.png (Download error or resource isn't a valid image)*

If you click on the png, you see it's the X logo, which is nowhere in my extension. It is on the page I'm modifying (twitter.com), and in the same vertical position (though I'm limiting the width so that it's not covered up).

The error doesn't seem to impact the functionality in any way, but I'd like to get rid of it. Any help would be appreciated!

*Note: This is similar to [SO 61138082](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61138082/error-while-trying-to-use-the-following-icon-from-the-manifest), but that's a react app and the file its complaining about is part of the app.*

Comment: This is an error from the site's manifest.json, not from your extension, so simply ignore it.

Comment: Thanks @wOxxOm, if there's nothing I can do, there's nothing I can do! I just hate that it pollutes my extension's error log

Comment: You can try to suppress it. If you see it in the extension's log it means your extension makes the request, so you can inspect it in devtools and find the header that sets manifest.json or that png url, then you can remove that header using declarativeNetRequest.