# Manifest.json in html importance

Tags: html, lighthouse, manifest.json

I am creating a website.

In Chrome's inspect, there is *Lighthouse* and it claims that I need a manifest. What is the point of having a manifest? Why would I need or not need one?

Lighthouse:

```
Web app manifest does not meet the installability requirements Failures: No manifest was fetched.
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Just FYI use Google and google the error message first, before asking here. Then if you still have questions ask them here so we can give you details you do not yet understand / add clarity. [The first result for "Web app manifest does not meet the installability requirements Failures: No manifest was fetched."](https://web.dev/installable-manifest/) explains things clearly & links to loads of information. Also before posting a question [search the site first](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45187030/2702894). Voting to close the question as it has been answered before.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is public/manifest.json file in create-react-app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45186993/what-is-public-manifest-json-file-in-create-react-app)

Comment: Also just to help you not get questions closed in the future [read the first answer to this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) so you know what is expected of users.

Answer (score 2):

See [this article](https://hackthestuff.com/article/what-is-manifest-json-file-and-how-it-is-useful). It tells chrome minimal information about your site, and you must include it if you want your users to have the "Add to Home Screen" option.