# What's the manifesto.json in create-react-app?

Tags: json, reactjs, icons, create-react-app, public

I created a react app and removed all of the react images that comes with it. The content of manifesto.json looks like this:

```
{
  "short_name": "React App",
  "name": "Create React App Sample",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "favicon.ico",
      "sizes": "64x64 32x32 24x24 16x16",
      "type": "image/x-icon"
    },
    {
      "src": "logo192.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "192x192"
    },
    {
      "src": "logo512.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "512x512"
    }
  ],
  "start_url": ".",
  "display": "standalone",
  "theme_color": "#000000",
  "background_color": "#ffffff"
}
```

What is it, and what should i add/remove from it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45186993/what-is-public-manifest-json-file-in-create-react-app#:~:text=The%20web%20app%20manifest%20provides,access%20and%20a%20richer%20experience


Refer this

Comment: @Thiluxan what can I add and remove from it?

Comment: You can add license details, contributor details, descriptions, and such things. It is like a description for your app

Answer (score 0):

The manifest. json is a simple JSON file in your website that tells the browser about your website on user's mobile device or desktop. Having a manifest is required by Chrome to show the Add to Home Screen prompt.

I keep this and add in images with the same size parameters that represent my app/website.