# Is it safe to delete the manifest.json file that comes bundled with create-react-app

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm a newbie to React development. I have read that the `manifest.json` file contains information about a Web App, and it may be useful in some cases. What am asking, though, is if it's safe to delete it.

Answer (score 7):

For information about what the manifest is for, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45187030/3083470) may help you but to answer your question:

Yes, you should be completely fine deleting the manifest.json as well as `<link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />` in `public/index.html`, so long as you're fine with losing the benefits it provides linked above.

Comment: So I'll be losing a lot of mobile benefits. Okay, thanks for taking the time to answer.

Answer (score 0):

yes,you delete manifest data  which doesn't give any impact in your project

Comment: What does that add to the accepted answer?