# adding link to react app to Android desktop

Tags: android, reactjs, google-chrome

I have created a react app, that I am hosting with render.com.
Now, I would like to have a shortcut to that site on my smartphone's home screen.

Usually I can do that by opening the site in Chrome, open the context menu and select the "add to home screen". But on this page I have the entry "install app" instead. Doing so will install an app called "React App" which also opens the website. I would be ok with that, if I could change the name of this "App". (Or at least the name of the link to the app on my home screen)

Can I do that somehow? Or can I get a Chrome-link like with other websites?

Comment: Do you have a `public/manifest.json` file in your react app? Can you [edit] the question to include it if you do? See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45186993/what-is-public-manifest-json-file-in-create-react-app

Comment: ok, found it in there. Thanks